# Функция-валидатор True/False при наличии условий в Python

Tags: python

> Напиши функцию-валидатор бронирования can_they_book, которая принимает
> количество взрослых adults_count и детей children_count и возвращает
> True, если выполняются все условия:
>
> 1. номер вмещает не более 8 персон
> 2. должен быть хотя бы один взрослый
> 3. на одного взрослого может быть
>    не больше двух детей
>
> Считай непереданные аргументы равными 0.

9 автотестов проходит, а вот 3 не проходит:

1. adult_count = 0, can_book = False
   TypeError: can_they_book() missing 1 required positional argument: 'children_count'
2. adult_count = 2, can_book = True
   TypeError: can_they_book() missing 1 required positional argument: 'children_count'
3. adult_count = 9, can_book = False
   TypeError: can_they_book() missing 1 required positional argument: 'children_count'

```
def can_they_book(adults_count: int, children_count: int) -> bool:
    if adults_count == 1 and children_count > 2:
        return False   
    if adults_count + children_count >= 9:
        return False   
    if adults_count == 0:
        return False
    if adults_count + children_count <= 8:
        return True
```

Comment: строчку "Считай непереданные аргументы равными 0." не прочитал?

Comment: Та читал и даже писал проверку: if adults_count is None or children_count is None: return 0, но не помогло, ну или опять же не правильно указал логику.

Comment: None это когда передают None, а не когда не передают совсем.

Comment: что писать когда не передают совсем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить значения по умолчанию

```
def can_they_book(adults_count = 0, children_count = 0)
```

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось

Answer (score 2):

> Считай непереданные аргументы равными 0.

```
def can_they_book(adults_count=0, children_count=0)
```

> 1. номер вмещает не более 8 персон

С этим бы хорошо исправились.

> 2. должен быть хотя бы один взрослый

Опять все в порядке.

> 3. на одного взрослого может быть не больше двух детей

Ваш код

```
if adults_count == 1 and children_count > 2:
    return False
```

нужно исправить:

```
if adults_count < 2 * children_count:
    return False
```

Теперь, когда все 3 проверки были успешными, не надо еще один раз проверять количество персон - значит, вместо вашего

```
if adults_count + children_count <= 8:
    return True
```

достаточно

```
return True
```